# Can't get a views/collection to show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I can't seem to get a test backbone.js app working and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

http://jsbin.com/iwigAtah/1/edit

Comment: Try this http://jsbin.com/iwigAtah/4/edit . First your `this.collection` is empty . Next convert the objects to json before dumping them using console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit and here's what I came up with.

```
// Backbone Objects
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    // collection is now passed in as an argument
    // this line isn't necessary but makes it easier to understand what is going on
    this.collection = options.collection;
    console.log(this.collection.models);
  }
});


// Create a new empty collection
var test = new List();

// Create a new item model and add it to the collection
var testItem = new Item();
test.add(testItem);

// Create a view with your new collection
var g = new ListView({
  collection: test
});
```

The main issue you were having is that you weren't actually adding your model to the collection.